# SAS: Data step view -> error: by variable not sorted properly

Tags: sorting, sas, dataview, datastep, wrds

I am using a macro to loop through files based on names and extract data which works fine for the majority of the cases, however from time to time I experience

```
ERROR: BY variables are not properly sorted on data set CQ.CQM_20141113.
```

where CQM_20141113 is the file I am extracting data from. In fact my macro loops through `CQ.CQM_2014:` and it works up until 20141113. Because of this single failure the file is then not created.

I am using a data step view to "initialize" the data and then in a further step to call data step view (code sample with shortened where conditions):

```
%let taq_ds = CQ.CQM_2014:;

data _v_&tables / view=_v_&tables;
     set &taq_ds;
     by sym_root date time_m; *<= added by statement
     format sym_root date time_m;
     where sym_root = &stock;   
run; 

data xtemp2_&stockfiname (keep = sym_root year date iprice);
     retain sym_root year date iprice; 
     set _v_&tables; 
     by sym_root date time_m;

/* some conditions */
run;
```

When I see the error via the log file and I run the file again, then it works (sometimes I need a few trials).

I was thinking of a proc sort, but how to do that when using data step view?
Please note the cqm-files are very large (which could also be the root of the problem).

edit: `taq_ds`is not a single file but runs through several files whose name start with `CQM_2014`, i.e. CQM_20140101, CQM_20140102, etc.

Comment: You could index &taq_ds. on sym_root date time_m, or create a sql view with an order by clause.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the code provided, you could replace your first data step view with a SQL one:

```
proc sql;
create view _v_&tables as
  select * from &taq_ds
  where sym_root = &stock
  order by sym_root, date, time_m;
```

Alternatively you could prefix your data step view with a similar view.  This would enforce the ordering needed for the subsequent `by` statement.

Comment: thanks @Allan Bowe: something that came into my mind: is it also somehow possible to integrate a part of code that says "if you occur an order-error (or maybe even any other error), skip the file and continue with the next one?

Comment: apologies, should have added how I define my variables:
`%let taq_ds = cq.cqm_2013:;` where I used SAS property to "loop" through all files with the name `cqm_2013mmdd`. What would I need to adjust in the proc sql statement?

Comment: yes - you can add a condition such as `%if &syscc ge 4 %then %do;` and implement logic to enable processing to continue (eg `options obs=max`)

Comment: ref your second comment - it's not very clear.   Perhaps you could make a new question?

Comment: thanks @Allan Bowe: I tried to wrap it in the `proc sql` statement, however I have the probmlem that `&taq_ds` is not a single file / table, but it's like a loop running through several tables; so `taq_ds = cq.cqm_2013:;`and there are like cq.cqm_20130101, cq.cqm_20130102 one file for each day; I suspect that this is not possible within `proc sql`. regarding the other question I will create a new one

Comment: new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50106168/sas-sort-error-by-variable-not-sorted-properly

Answer (score 1):

Creating an index on `taq_ds` corresponding to the `by` group order would also solve this, e.g.:

```
proc datasets lib=<library containing taq_ds>;
modify taq_ds;
index create index1=(sym_root date time_m);
run;
quit;
```

Comment: would that work in case my `taq_ds` is not a single file but a "loop" through several files?

Comment: You could do something equivalent by indexing each of the underlying datasets. Please update your question with further details.